# Parse XML into pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, xml, parsing

I am currently trying to analyze some voting behavior in the European Parliament, using the parliaments XML interface. However, even though I am able to import the information correctly, I am not able to transform them into a pandas DataFrame.

`data = pd.read_xml('https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/PV-9-2020-12-18-RCV_FR.xml', xpath='.//RollCallVote.Result')` gives me data frame size (39,7), where Identifier  is the first "layer" giving me the vote topic.

to get the vote results of these topic identifiers, meaning the elements `Result.For, Result.Against, Result.Abstention` as well as, more importantly, the Members who have voted in these categories accordingly. This requires to go down the tree through the sub notes of `Result.PoliticalGroup.List` and `PoliticalGroup.Member.Name` and then get them into the DataFrame format. However, unfortunately, I am not able to get a DataFrame out of it, e.g. when combining xpath I get the error message XPathEvalError: Invalid expression.

UPDATE:

I got something like

```
identifier_items = []
all_items = []
  
for allvotes in xmlroot.iter('RollCallVote.Result'):
    identifier_Nr = allvotes.attrib.get('Identifier')
    for_Votes = allvotes.find('Result.For').get('Number')
    against_Votes = allvotes.find('Result.Against').get('Number')
    abstention_Votes = allvotes.find('Result.Abstention').get('Number')
    
    identifier_items = [identifier_Nr, for_Votes, against_Votes, abstention_Votes]
    all_items.append(identifier_items)
  
xmlToDf = pd.DataFrame(all_items, columns=['Identifier', 'For_Votes', 'Against_Votes','Abstention_Votes'])
```

now, which gives me a data frame like this

```
    Identifier  For_Votes   Against_Votes   Abstention_Votes
0   126293      629         30               27
1   126294      633         6                46
2   126295      632         27               27
3   126296      643         8                35
```

However, if I want to iterate over every Identifier now to get some detailed information per MEP, with code like this:

```
identifier_items = []
all_items = []
  
for allvotes in xmlroot.findall('RollCallVote.Result'):
    identifier_Nr = allvotes.attrib.get('Identifier')
    for_MEP = allvotes.find('Result.For').find('Result.PoliticalGroup.List').find('PoliticalGroup.Member.Name').get('MepId')
  
    identifier_items = [identifier_Nr, for_MEP]
    all_items.append(identifier_items)
  
xmlToDf2 = pd.DataFrame(all_items, columns=['Identifier','For_MEP'])
```

the result is like this:

```
    Identifier  For_MEP
0   126293      7244
1   126294      7244
2   126295      7244
```

However, I would like to get something like this

```
    Identifier  For_MEP
0   126293      7244
1   126293      7245
2   126293      7246
3   126294      7244
4   126294      7245
5   126294      7246
6   126295      7244
7   126295      7245
8   126295      7246
```

Can somebody please help?

--- UPDATE ---

I managed to get it done by this, e.g. for vote of MEPs who voted for every report it:

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from itertools import product, chain
from urllib.request import urlopen


var_url = urlopen('https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/PV-9-2020-12-18-RCV_FR.xml')
xmldoc = ET.parse(var_url)
xmlroot = xmldoc.getroot()
vote_items = []
all_vote_items = []

for avote in xmlroot.iter('RollCallVote.Result'):
    vote_Nr = avote.attrib.get('Identifier')
    
    for anitem in avote.iter('Result.For'):
        vote_For_Result = anitem.attrib.get('Number')
        
        for agroup in anitem.iter('Result.PoliticalGroup.List'):
            vote_For_Group = agroup.attrib.get('Identifier')
            
            for amep in agroup.iter('PoliticalGroup.Member.Name'):
                mep_id = amep.get('MepId')
                
                vote_items = [vote_Nr, vote_For_Result, vote_For_Group, mep_id]
                all_vote_items.append(vote_items)
            
for_meps = pd.DataFrame(all_vote_items,columns=['vote_nr','vote_for_result','vote_for_group','mep_id'])
```

Now I would like to combine all votes (for, against, abstention) in one data frame. I thought about something like this:

```
vote_items = []
all_vote_items = []

for avote in xmlroot.iter('RollCallVote.Result'):
    vote_Nr = avote.attrib.get('Identifier')
    
    for anitem in avote.iter('Result.For'):
        for agroup in anitem.iter('Result.PoliticalGroup.List'):
            for amep in agroup.iter('PoliticalGroup.Member.Name'):
                mep_id_for = amep.get('MepId')
    
    for anitem in avote.iter('Result.Against'):
        for agroup in anitem.iter('Result.PoliticalGroup.List'):
            for amep in agroup.iter('PoliticalGroup.Member.Name'):
                mep_id_against = amep.get('MepId')
                
    for anitem in avote.iter('Result.Abstention'):
        for agroup in anitem.iter('Result.PoliticalGroup.List'):
            for amep in agroup.iter('PoliticalGroup.Member.Name'):
                mep_id_abstention = amep.get('MepId')
    
    
    vote_items = [vote_Nr, mep_id_for, mep_id_against, mep_id_abstention]
    all_vote_items.append(vote_items)
            
abstention_meps = pd.DataFrame(all_vote_items,columns=['vote_nr','vote_for','vote_against','mep_abstention'])
```

Yet, unfortunately, this does not work out. Does someone know the answer to this?

Comment: `.find('PoliticalGroup.Member.Name')` only finds the first member. I presume that you want all members that placed a "for" vote. Then you would need to use `findall()` instead of `find()`.

Comment: with ```for_MEP = allvotes.find('Result.For').find('Result.PoliticalGroup.List').findall('PoliticalGroup.Member.Name').get('MepId')``` I get the error message ```AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'```...

Comment: `findall()` returns a list. You need to iterate over that list and use `get()` on each item.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work either. I get the error message ```AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'get'```or ```AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iter'```. Do you have an example?

Comment: You already have `for allvotes in xmlroot.findall('RollCallVote.Result')`, followed by `identifier_Nr = allvotes.attrib.get('Identifier')`. You need something very similar to that.

Comment: Does not really help...even if I use ```identifier_items = []
all_items = []
  
for allvotes in xmlroot.findall('RollCallVote.Result'):
    identifier_Nr = allvotes.attrib.get('Identifier')
    for allvotes in xmlroot.findall('Result.For'):
        for_MEP = allvotes.attrib.get('MepId')
    
    identifier_items = [identifier_Nr, for_MEP]
    all_items.append(identifier_items)
  
xmlDF = pd.DataFrame(all_items, columns=['Identifier','For_MEP'])```I am stuck..

Comment: Code and error messages are hard to read in comments. You should edit the question. Try to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hi @mzjn I added a small example.. :)

Comment: There are several code snippets in the question. It is rather confusing. "I managed to get it done" - what did you get done exactly? If you have solved a problem, post it as an answer. If there are other issues, please ask a new question.

Comment: As @mzjn pointed out: if your problem is solved, post an answer, mark as accepted answer to allow other users getting help from it and prevent double questions.